# stuck with simple php looping logic

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `array` which can have any no. of elements in it. Now i want to loop this array and create design such that each `li` can have 15 elements inside it , next set of `li` will be created based of multiples of 15's elements.

Now my array has exact 15 elements and the code i am trying creating 2 `li` , which it should create only 1 `li`.

May be my logic is too bad or I am missing anything.

Here is my code:-

```
  <?php $result = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15); ?>
    <div class="slide">
    <?php $design = '<ul class="slides"><li><div class="MainSlider">';
        foreach($result as $key=>$row) 
        {
            $design .= '<div class="MainSliderPic">'.$key.'</div>';
            if(($key+1)% 15 == 0){
            $design .= '</div></li><li><div class="MainSlider">';
            }

            if(count($result) == $key+1){     
            $design .= '</div></li></ul>';
            }
        }
    echo $design;
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: `if(($key+1)% 15 == 0){` The % operator should be the problem it means if Remainder of $key divided by 15 is equals to 15 do this...

Comment: & just a little input:
On your 6th line you wrote'.$key.' ... sure you want to output the key and not the value? (Could be done by replacing $key with $row)

Comment: As per your condition, you have 15 records, so when your `modulo(%)` condition will be true it close the `li` and start again new `li`, and at last record it ends the `li` and div, so if you have `15, 30, 45 ...` records you will get an extra `li` which is blank

Comment: @Anant: I have upvoted each and every answer here , every answer has given me something to learn , so kindly stop pinging each day to Upvote , I am not getting exactly what you want me to do. I may have no idea because i am new here so please take a sorry from mysite and stop pinging.

Comment: After getting answer you need to mark one answer as accepted. I am not talking about up-vote, it's marking the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix opening and closing of tags in your code. Do it separately where it belongs, e.g.

```
$design = '<ul class="slides">';
$n = 0;
foreach($result as $key=>$row) {
    if ($n == 0)
        $design .= '<li><div class="MainSlider">';

    $design .= '<div class="MainSliderPic">' . $key . '</div>';

    ++$n;
    if ($n == 15) {
        $design .= '</div></li>';
        $n = 0;
    }
}

$design .= '</ul>';
echo $design;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) for to achieve it:

```
$result = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);

$chunks = array_chunk($result, 15);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo '<ul><li>';

    echo implode('</li><li>', $chunk);

    echo '</li></ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
<?php $result = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15); ?>
    <div class="slide">
    <?php $design = '<ul class="slides"><li><div class="MainSlider">';
        foreach($result as $key=>$row) 
        {
            $design .= '<div class="MainSliderPic">'.$key.'</div>';
            if((($key+1)% 15 == 0) && (count($result) != ($key+1))){
            $design .= '</div></li><li><div class="MainSlider">';
            }

            if(count($result) == $key+1){     
            $design .= '</div></li></ul>';
            }
        }
    echo $design;
    ?>
    </div>
```